# jFrame GetGraphics is null in java While Drawing image

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, jframe

I'm getting null exception error while drawing image to jframe.
i debug the code and check the image and frame is not null  but still it is throwing NULL exception while drawing image to frame.

Please have a look :

```
public void run(){
    try{

        ObjectInputStream objVideoIn = new ObjectInputStream(serVideoIn);
        byte[] imgbytes=null;
        ByteArrayInputStream barrin=null;


        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        Graphics ga=jf.getGraphics(); //Getting null exception 
                //Thread.sleep(10000);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(400, 400);


        while(true){
                    int index=0;
                    //Thread.sleep(300);
                    int size= (int)objVideoIn.readObject();
                    imgbytes = new byte[size];
                    barrin = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgbytes);
                    System.out.println("image size" + size);
                    //Thread.sleep(200);
                    while(index<size)
                    {
                        System.out.println("reading image");
                        int bytesread = objVideoIn.read(imgbytes, index, size-index);
                        if(bytesread<0){
                            System.out.println("error in receiving bytes yar");
                        }
                        index+=bytesread;
                    }
                    //barrin.read(imgbytes, 0, imgbytes.length);
                    barrin = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgbytes);

                    buffImg = ImageIO.read(barrin);

                        if(buffImg==null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("null received");
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("image received");

                        **ga.drawImage(buffImg, 0, 0, null);**


                        }
                    }

            }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("error reading video" +ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line throws the NPE? (and please don't just give us a line number...)

Comment: Here :  Graphics ga=jf.getGraphics(); //Getting null exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NPE is likely coming from here:

```
Graphics ga=jf.getGraphics();
```

as per [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphics%28%29):

> Creates a graphics context for this component. This method will return
>   null if this component is currently not displayable.

1) Dont use `Component#getGraphics` as its bad pratice/not persistent and will return `null` unless component is visible.

2) Rather use `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` dont forget to call `super.paintComponent(g);` as first call in overriden `paintComponent`.

3) Override `getPreferredSize()` and return correct `Dimension`s to fit image being drawn.

4) add `JPanel` to the frame for image to be visible of course.

Alternatively You could also use a `JLabel` which would require nothing more than a `setIcon(..)` call and be added added to `JFrame`.

Here are some of my examples:

Using `JPanel`:

- [Loading image in Java Code from C drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237908/loading-image-in-java-code-from-c-drive/13238468#13238468)
- [Image Drawing Works for JFrame, But Not JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073828/image-drawing-works-for-jframe-but-not-jpanel/13074097#13074097)
- [How to display an image in a frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996501/how-to-display-an-image-in-a-frame/12996718#12996718)
- [Convert a JPanel to an image in a JScrollPane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551646/convert-a-jpanel-to-an-image-in-a-jscrollpane/14551679#14551679)

Using `JLabel`:

- [Image resizing and displaying in a JPanel or a JLabel without loss of quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660122/image-resizing-and-displaying-in-a-jpanel-or-a-jlabel-without-loss-of-quality/12660146#12660146)