# Image not drawn in JPanel.paintComponent

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am actually want to load image but only applet dialog open and no error occurred but the image is not loading.the code is below here

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ball extends JPanel{
  Image image; 


  public Ball(){
    super();       
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/D:\\lolololo\\tuto\\bin\\sa.jpg");
  }

private Image getResource(String string) {
    return image;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){


   // Draw our Image object.
   g.drawImage(image,50,10,574,960, this); // at location 50,10
     // 200 wide and high
  }

  public void main(String arg[]){
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("ShowImage");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setSize(800,500);

   Ball panel = new Ball();
   frame.setContentPane(panel);
   frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: `"/D:\\lolololo\\tuto\\bin\\sa.jpg"`  should not contain the leading `/`.  It should be `"D:\\lolololo\\tuto\\bin\\sa.jpg"` presuming the rest of that path is correct.  As an aside `public void main(String arg[]){`  is **not** a valid method signature for the main method!

Comment: Given `Toolkit.getImage(String)` does not throw any errors when the image is not found, I prefer to use `ImageIO` to load them.  It provides lots of helpful output when anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are loading the image is wrong. This will never work when you extract as Runnable jar.

- Create package ("res") inside inside your src

Now load the image this way

```
image = ImageIO.read(Ball.class.getResource("/res/sa.jpg"));
```

This will work.

As indicated by Andrew in his comment main class should be

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @AndrewThompsons comments.

1) Below is incorrect, you do not honer the paint chain by calling the supers implementation of `super.paintComponent(...)`:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   // Draw our Image object.
   g.drawImage(image,50,10,574,960, this); // at location 50,10
   // 200 wide and high

}
```

[As per docs for paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29):

> Further, if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honor
>   the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must
>   completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not
>   honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

should be:

```
public class Ball extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage image;

    public Ball() {
       super();

       try {
           image=ImageIO.read(new File("c:/test.jpg"));//change to your path of file 
       }catch(Exception ex) {//file did not load properly
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         super.paintComponent(g);

         // Draw our Image object.
         g.drawImage(image,0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), this); // at location 50,10
        // 200 wide and high
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());//replace with size of image
    }

}
```

Also notice:

- I overrode `getPreferredSize()` of `JPanel` and returned `Dimension`s I wanted (i.e Image size) or the `JPanel` will only be as big as the components added to it and not the image (so if no components 0,0).
- I also chose `BufferedImage` vs `Image` and surrounded the statement with a try catch to check if any errors are thrown.
- I see you also had `g.drawImage(image,50,10...)` why 50 and 10 and not 0,0?

2) Also this (as @AndrewThompson has said):

`image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/D:\\lolololo\\tuto\\bin\\sa.jpg");`

No need for the */* thats only if its located in your classes package etc not when its on your HDD at a set location.

3) also as said by @AndrewThompson a main method should be:

`public static void main(String[] args){}`

Notice the static modifer applied other wise its just another method.

4) Also dont use `JFrame#setSize(..)`, rather use `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize` and than simply call `pack()` on `JFrame` instance before setting it visible.

5) Also please have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). especially the [Event-Dispatch-Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632998/null-exception-while-drawing-image-to-jframe/14633038#14633038)  answer which shows many examples of drawing images