# paint(Graphics g) prevents Components from being drawn

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint, paintcomponent

I have created a testing version to simplify the problem that I'm having for you guys:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel l = new JLabel("hello");
    JPanel cp;

    public Test(){
        setContentPane(cp = new JPanel());
        cp.add(l);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        //do absolutely nothing
    }
}
```

When you start up the program, you get to see a perfectly blank window. However, if you remove the paint method, the JLabel shows up! (I've had to search for this bug for ages, really). Now, how can I enable a window to both use graphics and regularly draw components?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not be overriding the `paint(...)` method of a top-level window since it is rarely necessary and often deleterious. See Dave's answer for more.

Answer (score 7):

1) You should not override `paint(..)` of `JFrame`, unless you have a specific purpose for that.

The correct method of drawing in Swing is to:

- Add  a `JPanel` to `JFrame`
- in `JPanel`, override [`paintComponent(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29%5C) and `getPreferredSize()` to return correct `Dimension`s which fit our drawing. 
  NB dont forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)` as first call in overridden `paintComponent` method as to honor the *paint chain*

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632998/null-exception-while-drawing-image-to-jframe/14633038#14633038) answer of mine which has a few examples for you.

- Also do not extend `JFrame` unnecessarilly.
- Dont call `setSize` on `JFrame` rather use a correct `LayoutManager` and/or override `getPreferredSize()` - usually done on a `JPanel` when we are drawing directly or the `JPanel` will have no size if no components are added, if they are it will only be as big as it needs to fit the components and not the image.
- and than call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible.

And just incase have a look [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) especially [Event-Dispatch-Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)